# How should I deploy XMPP server GCM on java so as to GCM can reach it and send the message?

Tags: deployment, server, xmpp

I have XMPP server on java, that has to receive messages from GCM server (now it is Firebase Cloud Messaging) I followed with this tutorial:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/xmpp-server-google-cloud-messaging/

I have wi-fi router and I can not open any ports on it.
How should I deploy this server so as to GCM can reach it and send the message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wi-fi router was not the problem, I don't need to open port for my server in order to GCM server will have possibility to send message to my App server

Library Smack https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smack solved all this questions
so I don't need to deploy my java server somewhere, it can be launched on my PC.